# Mediarecorder support/pollyfil for Safari

Tags: safari, html5-video, webrtc, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I wanted to record Laptop's webcam video stream on safari browser. 
I am accessing the stream on browser by using MediaDevices.getUserMedia(). 
It seems MediaRecorder interface will do the trick (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

However this isnt supported by Safari. 
Any recommendation on how i should record the webcam stream and build a video recorder that runs on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is nothing available for Safari at the moment.

Comment: Now in 2020, there is the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaRecorder polyfill to record audio in Edge and Safari.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-recorder-polyfill)